# What is the syntax for composing setter lenses?

Tags: haskell, setter, haskell-lens, lenses

I'm new to lens and I want to compose two "setter" operations to be equivalent to this state0 to new_state2 transformation:

```
  let new_state1 = field1 %~ (const newVal1) $ state0
  let new_state2 = field2 %~ (const newVal2) $ new_state1
```

What's the syntax for doing this?

Comment: I also highly recommend [this read](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funny enough, lenses compose just like functions: with a `(.)`:

```
setterAB :: Lens' A B
setterBC :: Lens' B C

setterAC = setterAB . setterBC
```

In your example, though, you don't want to compose lenses; you want to compose *transformations* (which is both the lens and the actual operation), and there are two ways to do that.

Oh, and before we actually get to that, let's simplify your code a bit, using `(.~)` ("set") instead of `(%~)` ("modify"):

```
let new_state1 = field1 .~ newVal1 $ state0
let new_state2 = field2 .~ newVal2 $ new_state1
```

#### Direct, via &

There's a fancy `&` operator that works pretty well. It's just `flip ($)`:

```
let new_state1 = state0 & field1 .~ newVal1
let new_state2 = new_state & field2 .~ newVal2
```

Which means you can now write:

```
let new_state = 
    state0 
        & field1 .~ newVal1
        & field2 .~ newVal2
```

#### Monadic

Even better, if you're actually having a `State` somewhere, you can get rid of that passing completely and put that in a monad:

```
let new_state = (flip execState state0) $ do
    field1 .= newVal1
    field2 .= newVal2
```

They are defined in terms of `MonadState`, so if you're in a monad stack, you can use that instance directly, or use `StateT` in order to get more effects available for the setters.